# Adding labels to a map with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, mapping

I did a map with ggplot() and I wanted to add labels to the map, or an interactive thing so that when I hover over the state area it gives me the name of it. I looked for tips in Stackoverflow however it is not working.
Do you have any suggestions?

[How my data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGSwf.png)

```html
scaling_map <-ggplot(pop_usa, aes(long,lat)) + 
geom_polygon(aes(group= group, fill = estimated_pop_2020) ,color="black") +
theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank(), 
axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),plot.title = element_text(face = "bold",hjust = 0.5)) +
  ggtitle("Estimated population by state") +
  scale_fill_gradient(name ="Estimated population (log10)" ,low = "#FFFFCC" , high = "#336600") +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = state))
  coord_map()
```

Here is the message that I got when I ran it:

```
Error in `geom_sf_text()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `compute_layer()`:
! `stat_sf_coordinates()` requires the following missing aesthetics: geometry
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 0):

with view to the error

> `'stat_sf_coordinates()' requires the following missing aesthetics: geometry`

try, instead of `geom_polygon`:

```
geom_sf(aes(group = group, fill = estimated_pop_2020, geometry = geometry) ,color="black")
```

and supply the geometry to geom_sf_text like so:

```
geom_sf_text(aes(label = state, geometry = geometry)) ## see note
```

note: unless the geometry column of your spatial dataframe `pop_usa` is named differently from the default "geometry"

Comment: Sorry , but I don't understand what object in my data frame should be equal to geometry , I added c(long,lat) because the coordinates of the area have be the label area. It gives me this : Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (14126)

Comment: What does `class(pop_usa)` return? If your dataframe pop_usa has not (also) class "sf", then geom_sf won't work. Either we need to convert pop_usa to a spatial dataframe, or use either of `geom_text`, `geom_label` or perhaps their versions from package {ggrepel}.

Comment: It returns data frame , I tried geom_text and geom_label but none of them worked.